# Deploying django project to elastic beanstalk using the command line. How to turn health to green?

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have been deploying a django project to elastic beanstalk using: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb When I deploy the environment health is green but after a few minutes it turns red and gives the explanation: "Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 requests/min) to determine application health. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances"

I can still view the website even though the health is severe. I am not sure how to fix this problem. The service role I use has the permission **AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk**. The EC2 instance profile I use has the permissions: **AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker**, **AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier** and **AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier**

The beginning of my **web.stdout.log**:

```
Jan 22 00:33:37 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2186]: [2024-01-22 00:33:37 +0000] [2186] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
Jan 22 00:33:37 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2186]: [2024-01-22 00:33:37 +0000] [2186] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2186)
Jan 22 00:33:37 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2186]: [2024-01-22 00:33:37 +0000] [2186] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Jan 22 00:33:37 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: [2024-01-22 00:33:37 +0000] [2194] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2194
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:33:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:34:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:05 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2186]: [2024-01-22 00:35:05 +0000] [2186] [INFO] Handling signal: term
Jan 22 00:35:05 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2194]: [2024-01-22 00:35:05 +0000] [2194] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2194)
Jan 22 00:35:06 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2186]: [2024-01-22 00:35:06 +0000] [2186] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jan 22 00:35:08 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2692]: [2024-01-22 00:35:08 +0000] [2692] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
Jan 22 00:35:08 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2692]: [2024-01-22 00:35:08 +0000] [2692] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2692)
Jan 22 00:35:08 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2692]: [2024-01-22 00:35:08 +0000] [2692] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Jan 22 00:35:08 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: [2024-01-22 00:35:08 +0000] [2720] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2720
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:18 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:26 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:33 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:41 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:48 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:49 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:35:56 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 150, in get_host
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    raise DisallowedHost(msg)
Jan 22 00:36:03 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:36:04 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Bad Request: /
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.31.31.20'. You may need to add '172.31.31.20' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = get_response(request)
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 133, in __call__
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    response = self.process_request(request)
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
Jan 22 00:36:11 ip-172-31-31-20 web[2720]:    host = request.get_host()
```